# Parse complex JSON string with newtonsoft json deserializer

Tags: c#, json

```
{
  "type": "xxx",
  "version": "1",
  "totalResults": -1,
  "resultsFrom": 0,
  "previousResultsUri": null,
  "nextResultsUri": "xxx",
  "exceptionNoticeUri": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "businessId": "xxx",
      **"name": "xxx",** <---- THIS ONE
      "registrationDate": "xx",
      "companyForm": "xxx",
      "detailsUri": null,
      "bisDetailsUri": "xxx",
      "language": "xx",
      "latestRegistrationDate": "xxx",
      "checkDate": "xxx",

 ....
```

This is the JSON response

I try to parse it with like so:

```
 dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(output);

            output = Convert.ToString(dynObj.results[0]);

            return output;
```

Which gives contains of the results-array. However when i try to get just the name type in the results with :

```
output = Convert.ToString(dynObj.results[0].name);
```

The set is empty. How do I get the name value from the results array?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Note that to keep it short, you really won't need much of that JSON...

Comment: (In particular, the code works for me...)

Comment: It works. Tested with v6.0.8.

Answer (score 3):

You could use http://json2csharp.com to generate this set of POCOs from your json:

```
public class Name
{
    public int order { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string registrationDate { get; set; }
    public object endDate { get; set; }
    public object language { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyForm
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string registrationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string postCode { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public object phone { get; set; }
    public object fax { get; set; }
    public string registrationDate { get; set; }
    public object endDate { get; set; }
}

public class RegisteredOffice
{
    public string registeredOffice { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string registrationDate { get; set; }
    public object endDate { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string businessId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string registrationDate { get; set; }
    public string companyForm { get; set; }
    public object detailsUri { get; set; }
    public string bisDetailsUri { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string latestRegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public string checkDate { get; set; }
    public List<Name> names { get; set; }
    public List<object> auxiliaryNames { get; set; }
    public List<CompanyForm> companyForms { get; set; }
    public List<Address> addresses { get; set; }
    public List<object> publicNotices { get; set; }
    public List<RegisteredOffice> registeredOffices { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
    public int resultsFrom { get; set; }
    public object previousResultsUri { get; set; }
    public string nextResultsUri { get; set; }
    public object exceptionNoticeUri { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

After that just call var `a = Jsonconvert.Deserialize<RootObject>(output);` and you can get your required value by `var output = a.Results[0].name;`

I'd advise not to use the `dynamic` keyword unless your json is truly dynamic.

Comment: You can also use EDIT menu -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes

Comment: Linkwise, JSONLint.com is a bit more worthwhile - it helps point out errors and how to fix it, one by one for faulty JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't need an answer but anyway here it is (working code):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/LioznP

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting my dev machine, this code works. I will classify this as: obsure

THX FOR THE SUPPORT!